# How to have fail2ban reprocess log files?

Tags: fail2ban

I have installed and started fail2ban. Looking at apache and secure log, there are clearly a lot spam. But fail2ban did not block anything yet

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT -v -n | less
fail2ban-client status
```

How do I  reprocess both secure and apache log to ban past hack attempts ?

Answer (score 0):

As Fail2Ban is simply looking at the log files as they are being written to, simply replay them.  You can do this by cat /path/to/old-log.file >> /path/to/log.file while fail2ban is running.  Note that this will, of-course, insert the old log file into the middle of your new log file, so you might want to rotate log files before and after you have done this.

That said I believe you are most likely "doing it wrong", as this is not what Fail2Ban is designed for.  Fail2Ban typically unbans IP's after a period of some minutes - AFAIK it does not have a built in mechanism to save bans, and its own manual describes it as *a  set  of server and client programs to limit brute force        authentication attempts.* - IE it is not designed for long-term bans - and nor should it be, as attackers IP addresses change, and you could very well land up denying service to legitimate users.  (It is designed to slow down brute force attacks - there is a 1800 times difference in time to brute force at a rate of say 5 passwords in 15 minutes and 10 per second.